Bad guys (main characters) tie up husband and rape wife; wife joins these bad guys after
American movie. Definitely available in the US.  
I just remember in one scene these bad guys (who were the main characters, making them sympathetic bad guys) break into some guy's house or hotel room. They tie up a husband and rape the wife, but the wife likes it because she's been getting tired of the husband anyway. Then the wife joins the bad guys. I want to say the rape happens in a bathroom. The guy is tied to the shower or a shower door I think, or he's tied to a chair. 
I believe the movie is set in the same time period it was released, so sometime in the 80's or 90's or so.
Could that be a scene from True Romance? It probably came out around that time, but I sometimes get my movie scenes mixed up.

It wasn't True Romance. That centered on Christian Slater and Patricia Arquette being chased by a drug lord (Christopher Walken) from the East Coast to sunny Los Angeles. No tied up husband, no raped wife.

Straw Dogs (1971) has a rape scene in which the wife (initially) enjoys the rape. Not otherwise a fit though.

That could be The Getaway, (1994).  Rudy, (Michael Madsen), isn't a sympathetic bad guy, though.

A wounded Rudy manages to drive himself to a local clinic, where he
  holds veterinarian Harold (James Stephens) and his wife Fran (Jennifer
  Tilly) hostage, then forces them to treat his wounds and drive him to
  El Paso. An attraction develops between Rudy and Fran and they taunt
  her meek husband. At a motel, Rudy has sex with Fran after tying
  Harold to a chair. Hearing his wife's moans and her laughter at him, a
  humiliated Harold commits suicide by hanging himself. Fran barely
  looks back as she accompanies Rudy to El Paso.

I remember Harold (and the audience) think Rudy is raping Fran, but when Harold manages to get to the door he sees that she is on top of him.

Nice guess, but as far as I remember Rudy was alone.

This might be it too.  The description does sound a little more likely, as Once Upon A Time In America is set in the past and I felt like the movie was set in the timeperiod it came out.

Finally watched it and this was the movie I was thinking of.  Thanks!

I love that movie, as well as the original McQueen version. "Ruuuudy, Ruuuudy, has anyone seen Ruuudy, "
